# An array of unknown size holding items with variable numbers of values/properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, data-structures

I'm using a datatable where for each row I want to store some 3 or 4 fields, the fields are of different types, best case number of fields is 3, and I want to note the row_index (of the row in the datatable) as I need it.

So like this I want to store the values (for the fields) for all the rows in the datatable.

Please give me an example, code snippet, or more information about how to structure/access this information for any nth row with the row index (which is also stored)

Comment: Although the original title would indicate a dupe, what he is asking for (including the ability for the items to hold an unknown umber of values/properties) makes it a unique question that just needs proper revision.

Comment: Ppl Can u pls help in this ..? It's urgent. I need a code snippet for declaring and accessing a field for any element in the array. I'm not sure if i can use ArrayList or List.. !!!

Answer (score 5):

Arrays must be assigned a length, to allow for any number of elements: use the [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class.

For example:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>();
myInts.Add(5);
myInts.Add(10);
myInts.Add(11);
myInts.Count // = 3
```

To store many values inside of the list, I would suggest creating your own class and storing that. But if you don't want to, you can have a list of lists of objects.

```
List<List<object>> myList = new List<List<object>();
myList.Add(new List<object>() { 1, "APPLE", "red", "sweet" } );
```

Comment: And he said array, so I doubt he wants something that does more than what an array could (outside of unknown length). Now, that's not to say he might not need something better.

Comment: using object is not such great advice; kind of defeats the purpose of using a strongly typed list!

Comment: And ArrayList or OrderedDictionary are strongly typed?

Comment: I can see several problems with this answer: 1) as Mitch said, you can't access individual elements by their index (you would have to iterate through if I am not mistaken?). 2) This doesn't the part of the question concerning each element having an indefinite amount of "values" or "properties"

Comment: @Samuel: based on the question I am guessing 1 and 4 wouldn't be indexes only because of the way he says Element[0] and Element[1]. I would imagine the 1 and 4 are some other type of property (perhaps something like a FruitID?)

Comment: @Mitch: Not sure where you are getting that, but System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary isn't generic.

Comment: Excuse my earlier brain fart, it is possible to access items in a List(of T) by index. Apparently my mind regressed momentarily back to linked lists in C++

Answer (score 1):

If you have absolutely no idea what fields can be in each element, your only choice is to create a property bag (map/dictionary) of key value pairs.

You can use an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(VS.71).aspx) or an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), which allow indexing by ordinal, to hold each property bag element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLDocument to store data. It is flexible enough to store and manipulate data even if you only need to use it in memory.